# How do I create 100 items and save to mongo db database

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, mongoose-schema, seeding

this is the code for creating a new item but how do I create 100 items

[this is the code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcgzF.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can async/await for saving 100 items.

```
createUser = async function(req, res) {
   for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
     var user = new User({
     });

     await user.save();
   }
}
```

Comment: Should I use an array to insert 100 users. writing 100 users in an array would be too long so is there any other option?

Comment: Where you gonna read data for users? It can be array and other things.